# Callback from the top stack of the UIController after PoptoViewController is called

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I just started programming in swift and I am struggling to understand how UIViewController access works.

Basically, I have a UIViewController that, after finishing its task, gets popped out using PopToViewController and return to another VC.

I wanted to attach a callback function to PopToViewController operation that calls a function that is located on the new top ViewController. This ViewController was already instantiated so I do not want to create a new one.

Basically what I have now is something like this

```
class CurrentController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func onButtonTap() {
        popViewController(animated: true)
        TargetController.dosomething()
    }
}
```

And the target controller (the one that I want do execute the function)

```
class TargetController: UIViewCOntroller { 
    func dosomething() { //I want to call this function right after pop happens without instantiating a new class
        //do something
    }
}
```

I tried some access methods but mostly all of them creating new instances or returning nil. Is there any easy way to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a **delegate** of the `TargetController` in your `CurrentController`. Then pass the instance of your `CurrentController` to that delegate. Now you can use this delegate to call the required method while popping the `CurrentViewController`.

```
class CurrentController: UIViewController {
    var targetViewControllerDelegate: TargetController!

    @IBAction func onButtonTap() {
        CATransaction.begin()
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { 
            targetViewControllerDelegate.dosomething() 
        }
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Now you have to set the delegate in the `TargetController` when you push the view controller.

```
class TargetController: UIViewController {

    func functionWhereYouPush() {
        let currentViewController = CurrentViewController()
        currentViewController.targetViewControllerDelegate = self
        navigationController?.pushViewController(currentViewController, animated: true)
    } 

    func dosomething() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

If you TargetController is not the direct parent then you'll have keep passing delegates till you reach the child, or use a Notification.